# Is there a public site to make and share live examples of C#/.NET code?

Tags: c#, .net, hosting, demos

For instance, [we now have that in the StackExchange universe for SQL Azure](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (which handles general SQL examples very well).

I was thinking it would be very nice to have a similar environment to be able to have a few class files and a console program to be able to demonstrate core basic C#/.NET programming techniques - **live**.

Is there such an online live C#/.NET environment already that we could use to post on StackOverflow?  (If not, I will post on Meta).

Comment: Snippet compiler is a handy tool for these types of examples. Would it be fair to say (for comparison's sake) that this would/should be like web-based version of snippet compiler?

Comment: @Paul Sasik - that is a cool tool, but that's not really what I meant by live.  I'm thinking something where you went to a web site (in any browser) and were able to see a small class or two and see the main() call them and see the output.  With ability to edit, see compiler errors, etc.  Then share a permalink and anyone could see the code live.

Comment: you're looking for Visual Studio Express.

Comment: @John Saunders I'm looking for Visual Studio Express Live.  I want to set up something where people don't have to download and open a solution/project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeRun:

http://coderun.com/ide/

Comment: This site let me do what I wanted to do to demo an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077961/how-to-delete-an-instance-of-a-class  Thanks so much for this site.  I'll leave the question open without accepting an answer just yet in case there are other great sites like this available.

Answer (score 3):

I found this one: Compilr

http://compilr.com/IDE/31-md5/

Lets you compile but not run - still pretty interesting.